# Get all event parameter values and event count using GA4 API

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I currently have a custom event with an event parameter called ‘term’. The value of this event parameter is whatever the user types on our search bar.

I would like to programatically get a report data on all the values that users have searched and how many times those terms have been searched. Just like this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqyDW.png)

I am trying to use the GA4 api https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1 to generate this report but I am unable to get the information I want.

I tried creating a custom dimension with event scope and I've set "term" as the event parameter. However when I try to run a report, it's empty

```
async function runReport() {
  const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
    property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
    dateRanges: [
      {
        startDate: '2021-03-31',
        endDate: 'today',
      },
    ],
    dimensions: [
      {
        name: 'customEvent:term',
      },
    ],
    metrics: [
      {
        name: 'eventCount',
      },
    ],
  });

  console.log('Report result:');
  response.rows.forEach(row => {
    console.log(row.dimensionValues[0], row.metricValues[0]);
  });
}
```

any other ideas on how I can achieve the report I want?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have successfully created the custom event and your custom parameter or custom dimension, the code below is written in java:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataSettings;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.DateRange;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.Dimension;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.Metric;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.Row;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.RunReportRequest;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.RunReportResponse;
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import io.grpc.LoadBalancerRegistry;
import io.grpc.grpclb.GrpclbLoadBalancerProvider;

public class test {

    static {
        LoadBalancerRegistry.getDefaultRegistry().register( new GrpclbLoadBalancerProvider());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar calendar  = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -2);
        String two_daysAgo=dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());    

        GoogleCredentials credentials =
                GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("path to your credentials"));

        BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings =
                BetaAnalyticsDataSettings.newBuilder()
                .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                .build();    

        try (BetaAnalyticsDataClient analyticsData =
                BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings)) {

            RunReportRequest request =
                    RunReportRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setProperty("properties/" + "your property Id")
                    .addDateRanges(DateRange.newBuilder().setStartDate("your start time").setEndDate(two_daysAgo))


                    .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("date")) 
                    .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("eventName"))
                    .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("customEvent:page_location")) 
                    .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("customEvent:your_custom_event_name"))

                    .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventCount"))
                    .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventsPerSession"))
                    .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventValue"))

                    .build();
            RunReportResponse response = analyticsData.runReport(request);

            for(Row row:response.getRowsList()) {
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n row is " + row.toString());
            }


        }

    }


}
```

I personally use the endDate 48 hours before since I prefer to make sure everything is updated.